# How to map object from API to Angular input text

Tags: angular, spring-boot, bulma

I am trying to read API response in Angular and display it in the input text field. I am able to call the API and print the response in the console but I am not able to capture response in the object and map it to the input field.

***Log API response :***

[image]

***m-fin.services.ts***

Service to call external API.

[image]

***networth-home.component.ts***

Trying to capture response in the variable.

[image]

***networth-home.component.html***

```
<div class = "account">
    <div class="field is-horizontal">
        <div class="field-label is-normal">
            <label class="label">Saving Account</label>
        </div>
        <div class="field-body">
            <div class="field">
                <div class="control">
                    <input class="input is-primary" type="text" placeholder= {{pages.account_amount}}>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

***Error :***

```
Error: src/app/networth/networth-home/networth-home.component.html:27:86 - error TS2339: Property 'account_amount' does not exist on type 'string'.

27                     <input class="input is-primary" type="text" placeholder= {{pages.account_amount}}>
                                                                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/networth/networth-home/networth-home.component.ts:6:16
    6   templateUrl: './networth-home.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component NetworthHomeComponent.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define an interface for the response you're getting from API. Currently Typescript infers the type of `pages` as `string` since you initialised it with `''`.

If the number of keys in the object are dynamic but of same type (number), you can probably do the following :

```
interface PagesItem {
 [key: string]: number;
}

pages: PagesItem[] = [];
```

In your html :

```
<input class="input is-primary" type="text" placeholder= {{pages[0]?.account_amount}}>
```